# Getting NaN instead in actual number when trying to fetch ID from

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table records with unique ID on each row. I am trying to fetch this ID, so I can use it in order to update these records, but I am unable to do so, since all I get from the data attribute is NaN, instead of the actual ID.

In the code below I've put the data attribute from which I am trying to fetch the id.

```
for( var i = 0; i < aUsers.length; i++ ){
  $("#lblUsers").append('<tr><th scope="row">'+aUsers[i].id+"<button class='btn btn-success' id ='editBtn' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editModal' contenteditable='false'>Edit</button>"+'</th><td>'+aUsers[i].username+'</td><td>'+aUsers[i].firstName+'</td><td>'+aUsers[i].lastName+'</td><td>'+aUsers[i].email+'</td><td>'+"<span data-i-user-id='"+aUsers[i].id+"'</span><input type='checkbox' id='chk_"+i+"'"+'</td></tr>');
}
```

And here is how I am trying to do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#editBtn").on("click", function() {
    var iUserId = parseInt($(this).closest("span").attr('data-i-user-id'));
    console.log(iUserId);
  });
});
```

Comment: What is the value of `$(this).closest("span").attr('data-i-user-id')`? I _think_ it is Not a Number.

Comment: Don't use `attr` to get a data attribute. use `data("i-user-id")`

Comment: _actually_ `.data('iUserId')` @SterlingArcher

Comment: *actually* [both work](https://jsfiddle.net/g6L1o03j/) @Neal

Comment: ha @rlemon the dashed version is deprecated ;-) but I know both work

Comment: The point here is use the data method, not the attr method.

Comment: True true @SterlingArcher :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons:

#### 1. Malformed HTML

You did not close the `span` tag:

```
<span data-i-user-id='"+aUsers[i].id+"'</span>
```

Should be:

```
<span data-i-user-id='"+aUsers[i].id+"'></span>
```

Note that the problem also repeats for the next element:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='chk_"+i+"'"+'</td>
```

I would suggest you create the nodes via the available DOM (or equivalent jQuery) methods, instead of providing a long HTML string, which typically leads to this type of problems.

#### 2. Wrong selector to find target element

This selector in the `editBtn` click hander does not match any element:

```
$(this).closest("span")
```

This is because `closest` looks only the parents of the button, but the intended `span` element is more like remote nephew of the button.

Instead write this:

```
$(this).closest("tr").find("span[data-i-user-id]")
```

That will find the parent `tr` element, which is the common parent of both the button and the targeted `span` element. Then it will search within the children of that `tr` element, the `span` element that has the `data-i-user-id` attribute.

The full correct statement looks like this:

```
var iUserId = parseInt($(this).closest("tr").find("span[data-i-user-id]").attr('data-i-user-id'));
```

Comment: thanks for the tips. I still get a NaN, though... Any idea why?

Comment: @user1866925 what is the value of the parameter that you are passing to the `parseInt`?

Comment: 1472752474350 this is an example value.

Comment: @user1866925 are you sure? maybe make a fiddle example

Comment: Your jQuery selector is also wrong. See my updated answer. If you would have debugged your code, you would have seen that `$(this).closest("span")` yielded no results. Debugging is a skill to develop ;-)

Comment: Did this answer suit your needs? Could you accept it or leave a comment?